# Facebook APP in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

The facebook app I have developed in Flex 4.5 using the ActionScript 3.0 sdk is for getting basic info like name, profile photo and date of birth, recent status and also to post a new status to facebook page. the app is a web application.

here is the link for the app "http://teens-group.com/adi/"

When i click on the login button the app opens a new window checking for the user name and password for facebook. when i login it doesn't refresh the app page and show me the logged in page. I have to re-fresh the app page again to go to the logged in page.

please help???

Comment: Why do you need to open a new window to check username and password in the first place?  And what do you mean "refresh the app page"? This isn't html you know...

Comment: I have added a link for the app "http://teens-group.com/adi/" you can check for your self what exactly the problem is???

Comment: Erm, no, I'm not logging in to grant you my information just because you want me to debug stuff for you.

Comment: no problem!!! i never asked to give me some information...

Comment: the app is not coded to send any info or grant permissions to me..... all it does is get a latest post from your wall and and display it in the app and also it will post a new status to your wall if you post any in the app. that's all it does

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you solved your problem or not. But this is a bug in the actionscript-facebook-api.The solution is to replace the code part in handleAuthResponseChange() function in Facebook.as

```
if (_initCallback != null) {
    _initCallback(authResponse, null);
    _initCallback = null;
}

if (_loginCallback != null) {
    _loginCallback(authResponse, null);
    _loginCallback = null;
}
```

with

```
if (_initCallback != null) {
    _initCallback(authResponse, null);
    if(authResponse != null) _initCallback = null;
}

if (_loginCallback != null) {
    _loginCallback(authResponse, null);
    if(authResponse != null) _loginCallback = null;
}
```